# CKEDITOR value NULL when inserting to db

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, ckeditor

Sorry for my bad english,
I wan't to inserting data to database with CKEDITOR and ajax submit, i have code

```js
$('#add').submit(function(e) {
 var fd = new FormData(this);
 e.preventDefault();
 // CKEDITOR.instances.isiForm.updateElement();
 for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances ) {
  CKEDITOR.instances.isiForm.updateElement();
 }
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url:  "blog_add",
  data: fd,
  cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
  success: function(result){
   if(result=='1'){
    table.ajax.reload(null,false);
     $('#add').modal('hide');
    // success result
   } else {
    // failed result
      }
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<form class="modal fade" id="add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Isi Post</label>
  <textarea id="isiForm" name="isiForm" cols="5" class="form-control rsf"></textarea>
 </div>
</form>
```

I have tried using CKEDITOR.instances.isiForm.updateElement(); but it not works, the value always NULL, so how can i insert to database with ajax? and i have try many thread but no one succeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the FormData BEFORE ckeditor has updated the textarea. Just switch it around so that the CKEDITOR elements are updated before you fetch the FormData.

EG (untested)

```js
$('#add').submit(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
  //first update the form values
 for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances ) {
  CKEDITOR.instances.isiForm.updateElement();
 }
  //then get the form data
 var fd = new FormData(this);
  //post via ajax
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url:  "blog_add",
  data: fd,
  cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
  success: function(result){
   if(result=='1'){
    table.ajax.reload(null,false);
     $('#add').modal('hide');
    // success result
   } else {
    // failed result
      }
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="modal fade" id="add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Isi Post</label>
  <textarea id="isiForm" name="isiForm" cols="5" class="form-control rsf"></textarea>
 </div>
</form>
```